# changing the legend of dotwhisker to custom values r

Tags: r

I have this sample of code in R, printing a regression model. I am trying to make the legend more readable than true/false.
How can input my own text? such as Significant or nonsignificant?

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
library(dotwhisker)
library(MASS)

flights <- nycflights13::flights
flights<- sample_n (flights, 500)

m1<- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ dep_time + origin+ air_time+ distance , data = flights)
#m1<- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ . , data = flights)

m1<- stepAIC(m1)
p<- dotwhisker::dwplot(m1)
p$layers[[1]]$mapping[5] <- aes(color = p.value < 0.05)
p$layers[[2]]$mapping[4] <- aes(color = p.value < 0.05)
p$labels$colour <- "Significant"
p$theme <- list()

z<- p + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dashed")+
  geom_segment(aes(x=conf.low,y=term,xend=conf.high,
                   yend=term,col=p.value<0.05)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=estimate,y=term,col=p.value<0.05)) +
  xlab("standardized coefficient") + 
  ylab("coefficient") +
  ggtitle("coefficients in the model and significance")
print(z)
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to change? There is no legend in `z` or `p`.

Comment: correct. edited the code slightly, this was an earlier version. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scale_color_hue` to change the labels.

```
library(ggplot2)

p + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dashed")+
  geom_segment(aes(x=conf.low,y=term,xend=conf.high,
                   yend=term,col=p.value<0.05)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=estimate,y=term,col=p.value<0.05)) +
  xlab("standardized coefficient") + 
  ylab("coefficient") +
  ggtitle("coefficients in the model and significance") + 
  scale_color_hue(labels = c('Significant', 'nonsignificant'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! One more questions as this i generated with multiple iterations - is it possible to make the colors consistent and not random? e.g - significant always orange or vice versa?

Comment: You can use `scale_color_manual` i.e `scale_color_manual(labels = c('Significant', 'nonsignificant'), values = c('red', 'green'))`

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts as to how to get the default colors? they were pretty nice